# Configure logging to pass text

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py

I am using [`discord.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) to create a bot. I would like to do one (either) of the following:

- redirect stdout to `discord.Client().send_message` so that all output goes to a channel in my Discord server
- configure logging to output to this function so that all log messages go here

Comment: If you are talking about errors you can do `on_error` and customize it to your liking. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.on_error

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. I hadn't considered that this might be implemented in the API.